# Python ISBN program

Tags: python, digit, isbn

I'm trying to calculate the check digit for an ISBN input on python. so far I have...

```
    def ISBN():
        numlist = []
        request = raw_input("Please enter the 10 digit number:  ")
        if len(request) == 10:
            **numlist == request
            print numlist**
        if len(request) != 10:
            print "Invalid Input"
            ISBN()

    ISBN()
```

The bold bit is where im having trouble, I cant seem to split the 10 digit input into individual numbers in the list (numlist) and then multiply the seperated individual numbers by 11 then the next by 10 then the next by 9 etc...
For the next part of the program, I will need to add these new multiplied numbers in the list together, then i will use the mod(%) function to get the remainder then subtract the number from 11, any assistance with any of my coding or incorrect statements on how to calculate the ISBN would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should get you on your way:

```
listofnums = [int(digit) for digit in '1234567890']
multipliers = reversed(range(2,12))
multipliednums = [a*b for a,b in zip(listofnums, multipliers)]
```

Strings are iterable, so if you iterate them, each element is returned as a single-character string.

`int` builds an int from a (valid) string.

The notation `[a*b for a,b in zip(listofnums, multipliers)]` is a list comprehension, a convenient syntax for mapping sequences to new lists.

As to the rest, explore them in your repl. Note that `reversed` returns a generator: if you want to see what is "in" it, you will need to use `tuple` or `list` to force its evaluation. This can be dangerous for infinite generators, for obvious reasons.

Comment: Perfect! thank you very much, this works perfectly from what i can see.

Comment: Actually, I have now found a problem related to my newer coding, no matter what I input, the "multipliednums" always come back as [11, 20, 27, 32, 35, 36, 35, 32, 27, 0]

Comment: @Novice_Python_Programmer Glad to have helped you on your way! People here really like receiving upvotes if their answers are helpful, and also acceptances for the best answer (as long as it substantially answers the whole question correctly).

Answer (score 0):

I believe `list()` is what you are looking for.

`numlist=list(request)`

Here is how I would write the code. I hope I'm interpreting the code correctly.

```
def ISBN():
    request = raw_input("Please enter the 10 digit number:  ")
    if len(request) == 10:
        numlist = list(request)
        print numlist
    else:
        print "Invalid Input"

ISBN()
```

Comment: Only, that list will have strings. If anything, he wants map(int, numlist)

Answer (score -1):

```
import itertools

if sum(x * int(d) for x, d in zip(nums, itertools.count(10, -1))) % 11 != 0:
    print "no good"
```

Comment: This is not an answer. In particular, it does not answer certain questions, and it contains at least one error.

Comment: I leave it to you to figure it out.

Comment: Wow, you're helpful. Yes, I copy pasted it from my repl, where nums was a list of ints.

Comment: There's a different error; the assumption that it was ints I considered an unanswered question.