# turn multiplication sequence into loop?

Tags: python

can anyone encorporate a loop into this code:

```
ISBN=input('Please enter the 10 digit number: ')

while len(ISBN)!= 10:
print('Please make sure you have entered a number which is exactly 10 characters long.')
ISBN=int(input('Please enter the 10 digit number: '))
continue
else:
    Digit1=int(ISBN[0])*11
    Digit2=int(ISBN[1])*10
    Digit3=int(ISBN[2])*9
    Digit4=int(ISBN[3])*8
    Digit5=int(ISBN[4])*7
    Digit6=int(ISBN[5])*6
    Digit7=int(ISBN[6])*5
    Digit8=int(ISBN[7])*4
    Digit9=int(ISBN[8])*3
    Digit10=int(ISBN[9])*2
    Sum=(Digit1+Digit2+Digit3+Digit4+Digit5+Digit6+Digit7+Digit8+Digit9+Digit10)
    Mod=Sum%11
    Digit11=11-Mod
    if Digit11==10:
       Digit11='X'
    ISBNNumber=str(ISBN)+str(Digit11)
    print('Your 11 digit ISBN Number is ' + ISBNNumber)
```

Comment: Why does this question keep getting asked? Is it from some course? Previous versions [one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15558881/553404) [two](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9707185/553404) and [three](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21409316/553404)

Comment: You do realize that you could have simply edited [your last post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21245108/198633), instead of making a new one. Next time, don't make multiple posts, just because the first one failed. That behavior is not looked upon very favorably by the community ;]

Comment: Wow, I'm getting sick of this question...

Comment: Also... please format the code in your post. I hate having to be an XSLT parser for python

Answer (score 2):

```
sum(int(v)*(11-i) for i,v in enumerate(ISBN))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in xrange(11):
    sum+=ISBN[i]*(11-i)
```

Comment: just an aside you are almost always better doing `for i,val in enumerate(values)` than i in range

Comment: Somewhere I read that for smaller valuer, it doesn't make much difference.

Comment: i meant more in terms of readability, performance difference is negligible im sure (+1 all the same since its nice and straightforward and closest to OP's original code)

Comment: Edit: replaced `range` by `xrange`.

Answer (score 1):

How about a nice, one-liner:

```
Sum = sum(d*i for d,i in zip(ISBN, range(11,0,-1)))
```

Comment: bah you beat me :P (+1)

Comment: @JoranBeasley: Your post is still valid. I use `range`, whereas you use `enumerate` and `11-x`

Comment: I guess ... :/ same idea though :P